# Longer crank time

Tags: engine, ac

Today I noticed something strange with my car. I was at a gym studio when I turned the key and I noticed it took a few "er er"'s longer before it started. As anxious I am about my expensive toys, I let it run for 30 sec, switched it off and started again - no problems this time.

Going home from work this evening, I turned the key - glowplug icon lit up, went off a second later, and another second later I started. It cranked way longer than before. Usually it would go like "Eerr vroooomm", now it went like "Er er er er er er vroooom". No problems after starting the engine in regards to driving.

Could this be due to leaving the A/C on? The last couple of days, I haven't turned it off due to high humidity air - and surprisingly enough - this is the first time it has ever happened.

(Ambient temp around 15 celsius)

I got the car a few months ago, and have always been enabling/disabling A/C during operation, never left it on before now - neither did the previous owner (positive).

**Could this be the culprit?** I turned off A/C about 5 min before arriving home now, and I'll try to go out to start it and go for a short drive in a couple of hours to see if that makes a difference.

Should it be required, my car is a Volkswagen Transporter T5 (2007) 1.9L TDI

Comment: Welcome to the site. How old is the battery?

Comment: Well I'd say it's about time to replace it then :). Have it tested before you declare it weak though.

Comment: I see, at least that calmes my nerves ;) Looks like new batteries aren't way too expensive either. But I'll get it tested asap I can, and meanwhile be sparesome with electricity after engine stop

Comment: @Zaid went out for a drive now, was basically like normal now - except for a slight little "cough" when it went from starter to idle - but once started it runs perfect. I'll be sure to not use any electricity after I stop the engine until I get it checked

Comment: You turned on the air conditioning in 15C? Why?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how leaving an A/C on would contribute to longer cranking, since most if not all modern vehicles will disable auxiliaries (e.g. A/C blower fan, radio) during cranking.

A longer crank is usually a telltale sign of lack of sufficient charge from the battery. If your battery hasn't been replaced in a while it would be a prime suspect for what you're observing.

Comment: Shouldn't the cranking be noticeably slower, though?